# QtWebBrowser macOS Signing Issue

Tags: macos, qt, signing, qtwebengine

I have recently run into a strange issue related to the QtWebBrowser on macOS. The QtWebEngine control doesnt seem to be loading outside of my development machine. I have tracked it to the signing. If I build the application and do not sign it, I can run it fine on another machine. As soon as I sign the application, the QtWebEngine control stops loading on other machines. It got even weirder when I went back to test an older version and it did the same thing. It is a version that I built and tested previously and was definitely working. Im fairly certain the computer I am testing with wasn't updated since then.

Something that seems like it might be a clue is a warning that is showing up now. I dont remember seeing it before.

```
2019-04-28 22:11:30.247507-0700 QtWebEngineProcess[30607:140529] [User Defaults] Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x106f08560> (Domain: com.apple.universalaccess, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): accessing preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access
```

Here is the command I am using to sign the application.

```
sudo codesign --deep --force --verify --verbose --sign "Developer ID Application: ***" --options runtime Output/MyApp.app
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue after much trial and error. I am fairly certain this will need to be done for anyone who is attempting to notarize a macOS application using the QtWebEngine. Hopefully this will save someone some time in the future.

The solution for me was to sign the QtWebEngineProcess with with the com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection exception. Here is the process.

Sign the main application with the following command

```
sudo codesign --deep --force --verify --verbose --sign "Developer ID Application: ***" --options runtime MyApp.app
```

Create an entitlements file for the QtWebEngineProcess

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Sign the QtWebEngineProcess with the following command

```
sudo codesign --force --verify --verbose --sign "Developer ID Application: ***" --entitlements QtWebEngineProcess.entitlements --options runtime MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/QtWebEngineProcess
```

Sign the main executable with the following command

```
sudo codesign --force --verify --verbose --sign "Developer ID Application: ***" --options runtime Output/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
```

After following these steps I am able to successfully notarize the application.